# Admin gets logged out when looking at user profile

Tags: 7, users, sessions

Every time I log in as admin and view a user profile, Drupal treats me as that user.  This is beneficial.  However, in order to return to the admin panel I need to log out of that user account and log in again as the admin.  What's going on here?  What mechanic causes this to occur and can I turn it off?

For the record, this is Drupal 7

Edit:
This is happening when I redirect the admin to a page usually restricted to special users.  Such as `mysite.com/user` or `mysite.com/vendor_orders` which is a special page I created in my own custom module.

Comment: How are you getting to the profile pages?  If you do the same thing as anonymous, do you automagically get logged in?

Comment: No anonymous gets redirected to a login page.  This happens when I click on the users information in the admin panel.

Comment: I have the same problem when go to homepage...

Comment: This also occurs when creating a new user as admin. Which is especially annoying when the site is in maintenance mode!